# Toggle for Phone View

Tags: css, toggle

I have toggle code but it doesn't manifest on a phone view. If I delete the max-width 750px it then appears but that messes up the comp view. So I can't have both the comp and phone view correct at the same time as my code is written now. https://citizenssalon.com

```
<!-- Header -->
        
<nav class=menu> 

            <nav class=title>CitizensSalon

            <ul class="active">        

        <link href="Policy.html">

        <link href="Writings.html">

         <link href="Projects.html">

        <li><a href="Writings.html">Blog</a></li>

        <li><a href="Policy.html">Policy Proposals</a></li>

        <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>

                </ul>

        </nav>

            

        <a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>

</nav>
```

CSS Code

```
/*----- Toggle Button -----*/


.toggle-nav {

    display:none;
  
}

/*----- Comp View Full Screen -----*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) 

{

  .wrap {

    width:90%;

  }

  .title {

      margin-bottom: 5px;

  }
  
}

/*----- Menu -----*/
  
@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
    
.menu {

      width:100%;

      box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);

      border-radius:3px;

      background-color:cadetblue;

      border: 10px;


    }

      .salon {

          font-size: 5px;

          margin-bottom: 10px;

      }
      .title {
          
font-size:30px;
      }
  
  .menu ul {

    display:inline-block;

  }



  .menu li {

    margin:0px 50px 0px 0px;

    float:left;

    list-style:none;

    font-size:17px;

    margin-top: 10px;

  }



  .menu li:last-child {

    margin-right:0px;

  }



  .menu a {

    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    color:black;

    transition:color linear 0.15s;

    font-size:20px;

    

  }



  .menu a:hover .menu .current-item a {

    text-decoration:none;

    color:#66a992;

  }



  @media screen and (max-width: 970px) {

    .search-form input {

      width:120px;

    }

  }



  @media screen and (max-width: 750px) {

      .menu {

      position:relative;

      display:block;

      background-color:cadetblue;

    }



    .menu ul.active {

      display:none;

    }



    .menu ul {

      width:20%;

      position:absolute;

      top:10%;

      right:10px;

      padding:10px 10px;

      box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);

      border-radius:3px;

      background:aliceblue;

    }



    .menu ul:after {

      width:0px;

      height:0px;

      position:absolute;

      top:0%;

      right:22px;

      content:'';

      transform:translate(0%, -100%);

      border-left:7px solid transparent;

      border-right:7px solid transparent;

      border-bottom:2px solid #303030;

    }



    .menu li {

      margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;

      float:none;

      display:block;

    }



    .menu a {

      display:inline;

    }



    .toggle-nav {

      padding:10px;

      float:none;

      display:inline-block;

      box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);

      border-radius:3px;

      background:white;

      text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

      color:black;

      font-size:30px;

      transition:color linear 0.15s;

    }



    .toggle-nav:hover .toggle-nav .active {

      text-decoration:none;

      color:#66a992;

    }

    .search-form {

      margin:12px 0px 0px 20px;

      float:left;

    }



    .search-form input {

      box-shadow:-1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

    }

  }

  .menu {

    text-align: center;

    border-radius: 2px;

}



.title {

    display: inline-block;

    border-top: 5px solid black;

    border-radius: 0px;

    font-size: 5.5rem;

    color:azure;

    font-family:monospace;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close your first `@media` declaration with a `}`, so all your CSS code is inside of `@media screen and (max-width: 1150px)`

Here's the fixed CSS:

```
/*----- Toggle Button -----*/
.toggle-nav {
  display:none;
}
/*----- Comp View Full Screen -----*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) 
{
  .wrap {
    width:90%;
  }
  .title {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
/*----- Menu -----*/
@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
  .menu {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius:3px;
    background-color:cadetblue;
    border: 10px;
  }
  .salon {
    font-size: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .title {
    font-size:30px;
  }
  .menu ul {
    display:inline-block;
  }
  .menu li {
    margin:0px 50px 0px 0px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    font-size:17px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .menu li:last-child {
    margin-right:0px;
  }
  .menu a {
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:black;
    transition:color linear 0.15s;
    font-size:20px;
  }
  .menu a:hover .menu .current-item a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#66a992;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 970px) {
  .search-form input {
    width:120px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .menu {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    background-color:cadetblue;
  }
  .menu ul.active {
    display:none;
  }
  .menu ul {
    width:20%;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    right:10px;
    padding:10px 10px;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:aliceblue;
  }
  .menu ul:after {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    right:22px;
    content:'';
    transform:translate(0%, -100%);
    border-left:7px solid transparent;
    border-right:7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:2px solid #303030;
  }
  .menu li {
    margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;
    float:none;
    display:block;
  }
  .menu a {
    display:inline;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    padding:10px;
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:white;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:black;
    font-size:30px;
    transition:color linear 0.15s;
  }
  .toggle-nav:hover .toggle-nav .active {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#66a992;
  }
  .search-form {
    margin:12px 0px 0px 20px;
    float:left;
  }
  .search-form input {
    box-shadow:-1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }
}
.menu {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 5.5rem;
  color:azure;
  font-family:monospace;
}
```

Comment: wow that's embarrassing. Thanks so much for the extra pair of eyes!

Comment: No problem @Jack! Always good to have an extra pair of eyes. If that solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer, that way you help the community environment we have here in SO :)